# Shared code in a google cloud function in different regions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I have the same exact google cloud function that I'm deploying to 2 different regions; for my European customers, none of their data can leave their country. Is there a way that I can share the code within my cloud function so that I can access the same code in the 2 different regions while having the 2 distinct endpoints?

```
   functions.http('helloHttp', async (req, res) => {
           //all the code I want to share is here!
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define your function implementation within the call to the `functions.http` method.  You can simply put it in its own function or variable and pass it wherever you need it.

```
async function shared(req, res) {
    //all the code I want to share is here!
}

functions.http('helloHttp1', shared)
functions.http('helloHttp2', shared)
```

Comment: I think I must be misunderstanding something fundamental.  In my current implementation of 2 different google cloud functions, one in the US and one in the UK.  And, the code is identical (ick!).  Based on what I see above, I think I would still have to copy the shared code and put it in the separate google cloud functions.  If I put  functions.http('helloHttp1', shared) in the US and functions.http('helloHttp2', shared) in the UK, where would I put the shared function so that it is defined in a single place?

Comment: In another file.  Import or require the function from the file just like you would any other javascript import.